# Downloading workbook without saving it to disk rubyxl in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubyxl

```
Rails 4.2
RubyXL
```

I am using the RubyXL to create a workbook. I can write it disk with:

```
workbook.write("path/to/desired/Excel/file.xlsx")
```

and then download it with something like this:

send_file(workbook.write("path/to/desired/Excel/file.xlsx"), options = {:filename => 'myworkbook.xlsx', :disposition => 'attachment'})

Any suggestions on how to download it without having to save it to the server first?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may convert workbook directly to a string:

```
def get_worksheet_as_string
  workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new
  # Fill workbook here or leave as is to download empty
  send_data workbook.stream.string, filename: "myworkbook.xlsx",
                                    disposition: 'attachment'
end
```

Comment: It did not work. The error message is that I am getting a nil in the stream. When I save it to disk, it works fine.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper It is working in my code, I don't know what difference may cause such behavior. Can you try to replace `string` with `read`? It should return this same result, but I'm guessing what is wrong...

Comment: Updated my answer with method I tried a while ago. In this state it works as expected. You can try this and then inspect, what modification of the workbook means that it stop working.

Comment: Nice! This should be in the docs. I didn't know you needed to convert to string.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in Sinatra:

```
get '/download-xlsx/?' do
    content_type 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    attachment(filename = "filename.xlsx", disposition = :attachment)

    workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new

    # Fill the workbook with data

    workbook.stream
end
```

Thought it might be helpful for those working in Sinatra!